# Retrieveing the values from database selecting or deselecting the checkboxes JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There is a problem in my jQuery. I want to retrieve the data from the database using AJAX.How I select and pass to the php file these values and get the multiple values.

For Example- when I **select the checkbox** the ajax will **return the value of the selected checkbox**. If I **unselect the same checkbox** then the value will be  **removed**.

here the checkboxes are:

checkboxes.php

```
<div class="block1">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="deep cleaning"/>Deep Cleaning</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="dishes"/>Dishes</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="move in/out"/>Move in/out</label>
</div>
<div class="block1">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="inside cabinets"/>Inside Cabinets</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="inside fridge" />Inside Fridge</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="inside oven" />Inside Oven</label>
</div>
<div class="block1">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="interior windows" />Interior windows</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="laundry + folding" />Laundry + Folding</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="green cleaning" />Green Cleaning</label>
  </div>
  <div class="block1">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="organization" />Organization</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" value="wipe window blinds" />Wipe Window Blinds</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <span id="cost"></span>
</div>
```

here the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var check=[];
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var check=$(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val());
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:{ "extra" : check},
      dataType : "JSON",
      url : "login.php",
      success:function(response){
        if(response){
          totalCost=10+response;
          $('#cost').text(totalCost);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

here the php code-

```
if (isset($_POST['extra'])) {
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select price from extras where name_of_extra ='$_POST[extra]'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
       echo json_encode($row['price'],JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
}
```

database image-

[image: image of database]

I want to **check the multiples and recieve multiple values through ajax and when i unselect the checkboxes then the value will remove from the span total**. if there is any mistake then i m sorry. i am a bigner. i hope you all will support me do better thnku in advance.

Comment: before u empty   $('#cost').html(" ");

Comment: @ranjith hello sir, i don't geting you can you please  tell me more.

Comment: @Puneet I posted answer you just need to copy paste it and it will works. In case you don't understand anything ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<label>Total amount : </label>
<span id="totalCost">0</span>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var check = []; 
      $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
         var checked = 0; // assigning ZERO for unchecked
         if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) { // checking checkbox status
            checked = 1; // ONE for checked
         }
         var totalCost = $("#totalCost").text(); // getting previous totalcost
         var check = $(this).val();
         // two parameters
         // data json object 
         // callback function
         getData({"extra": check}, function (response) {  
            var content = '';
            if (response) { //response is json object 
               if (checked) { // if checkbox is checked
                  content = '<div id="' + response['id'] + '">' + response['price'] + '</div>';
                  //create another variable which have div with price and id
                  totalCost = parseInt(totalCost) + response['price'];
                  // add new price in previous price
               } else {
                  $('#' + response['id']).remove();
                  // remove price div targeting with id
                  totalCost = parseInt(totalCost) - response['price'];
                  // subtract price from previous price
               }
               $("#cost").prepend(content); // prepend new content
               $("#totalCost").html(totalCost);
            }
         });
      });
      function getData(data, callback) {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "login.php",
            success: callback
         });
      }
   });
```

**Changes in php code**

```
if (isset($_POST['extra'])) {
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from extras where name_of_extra ='$_POST[extra]'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
       echo json_encode($row,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will works well. but can u help me to add this  value in the total amount. @adnanhaider

Comment: you want to show total amount of selected checkboxes. AM i right ?

Comment: can u little explain it for me please. i am done what i want to do. but if u explain it then it would be very helpful for my future.

Comment: sir, if you explain it from starting them its osm :) @adnanhaider

Comment: Ok I am adding comments again each step in answer.

Comment: once again thnku sir to giving me this answer

Comment: hey @adnanhaider can you help me in other question see i recently post a question can u help me

Comment: Sure i will try.

Comment: see in my profile **How to retain the values in the text field with Radio buttons using JQuery** @ adnanhaider