# Alert is not working in Ajax Success function?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am taking the zipcode from an input type and searching in database for that zip, if the zip is found, then I redirect the website to the specified location in database for that zip, but in case if zip is not there, then I want to alert a message of "invalid zip".

My code are as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#esubmit').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var postal = $('#epostal').val();
        var count = postal.length;
        if(count>6){
            alert("Invalid Postal Code");
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',   
                url: ajax_url,
                data: { action: 'postalcode', postal:postal },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response){
                        window.location.assign(response);
                    } else if(response=="") {
                        alert("Invalid Postal Code");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

    add_action('wp_ajax_postalcode', 'postalcode');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_postalcode', 'postalcode');
    
    function postalcode(){
        $postal = $_POST['postal'];
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'Service Zip Codes' AND meta_value LIKE '%$postal%')";
         $result = $wpdb->get_row($sql, OBJECT); 
         $ziparr =  $result->post_id;
         $sql2 = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'Franchise URL' AND post_id = '$ziparr')";
        $result2 = $wpdb->get_row($sql2, OBJECT);
        $ziparr2 =  $result2->meta_value;
        if($ziparr2){
        echo $loc = get_site_url()."/".$ziparr2;
        } else {
            echo $loc = "";
        }
        die();
           
    }
```

What I am doing is that, if I get the location for the zip, then I redirect that, and it is working fine...but when I could not found an entry for the entered zip, then I am storing the variable `$loc` empty, and checking where the response is empty, then alert the message, also I tried DOM methods like `text()`, but for the empty response, it is not working. Please help me through this.

Comment: use dataType: "json" and try

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(response);`? (in both cases, when data come as well as didn't come)

Comment: When the entered zip has entry in database, then it is showing the correct value in console and also working fine. But the problem starts with when the entered zip do not match in database, and it is showing nothing in the console or blank.

Comment: $.ajax will not return anything in your else condition. To achieve this you need to use the callbacks. Follow this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879911/1939258 If you still feel difficulty let me know.

Comment: but call back is also not working, neither alert nor dom methods are working.

Comment: @Umar update question, how you scripted now with callback.And also add the HTML.